# Developing networks in R using graph

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I am extremely new to R. I need to built a gene network. I have a list of genes and their corresponding motifs. I know that my genes will be my vertices and the motifs will be my edges. I know I have to make a data frame first. So, how can I make a data frame that could be plotted from the following?

```
>GENE1

hsa-miR-24-1-5p    
hsa-miR-24-2-5p    

>GENE2

hsa-miR-124-5p
hsa-miR-223-5p
hsa-miR-203a
hsa-miR-219-1-3p   

>GENE 3

hsa-miR-124-5p
hsa-miR-203a   

>GENE 4

hsa-miR-203a
hsa-miR-221-3p
hsa-miR-222-3p
hsa-miR-24-1-5p
hsa-miR-24-2-5p   

>GENE 5

hsa-miR-192-3p   

>GENE 6

hsa-miR-223-5p
hsa-miR-124-5p   

>GENE 7

hsa-miR-221-3p
hsa-miR-222-3p
hsa-miR-219-1-3p
```

Comment: It is not possible to produce a network with 4 edges and 3 nodes.  Does your real network have more nodes?

Comment: if you specify a feasible network, I can help you create one using 'igraph'.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll edit my question and put in actual data.

Comment: I hope this is a feasible network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closer, but your data looks a little funny.  There are many different ways to provide data to igraph in a form that it can interpret.  You should determine for yourself which for you like.  I prefer the edgelist format, so I present that here.  This format requires you define a source and destination of every edge.  You can see in the example below that I use the third column in the CSV to provide attribute data to igraph which allows me to label the edges using the plot function.

Here's an example of something you could write:

```
library(RCurl)
library(igraph)

el <- read.csv(text = "Source,Target,name
               GENE1,GENE2,hsa-miR-24-1-5p
               GENE2,GENE3,hsa-miR-124-5p
               GENE2,GENE4,hsa-miR-223-5p")
nodes <- read.csv(text = "Node
                  GENE1
                  GENE2
                  GENE3
                  GENE4")

g <- graph.data.frame(el,directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes)
plot(g, edge.label=E(g)$name)
```

There are a few requirements in the edgelist.  The first column is defined as the source column and the second column is the target.  In a directed network, arrows are drawn from source to target.  In an undirected network, this is irrelevant.

All edges need both source and target.  You need to check your network to ensure this is satisfied.

[This](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/igraphbook/igraphbook-flows.html) is a great resource starting out.  It doesn't help much with taking raw data and turning it into networks because the examples utilize built-in networks.